# Pass variables from one makefile to another

Tags: makefile

Let's say I have a makefile like this:

```
build:
    # output will be something like dist/foo-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
    poetry build

upload: build
    aws s3 cp ${WHEEL_NAME} s3://some-bucket/
```

The name of the wheel is obviously always changing and so it will somehow need to be recorded at the end of `build` and read at `upload`. What is the correct way of implementing this?

Comment: There are several ways to do it. Does `build` have any use for the name of the wheel? Might you ever want to run `build` *without* then running `upload`? Do you have any reason to keep the local copy of the wheel?

Comment: @Beta The intended platform for this would be a CI server. Hence, Q1) No. Q2) Yes, when doing manual testing. Q3) No, except when doing manual testing.

Comment: To be clear though, I *do* want the wheel name to contain the version so that users of the wheel can easily tell the version from the filename. So simply renaming the wheel to a static filename (eg. `foo-latest-py3-none-any.whl`) wouldn't work here, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple approach. Instead of `dist/`, use a directory whose sole purpose is to contain the latest wheel:

```
WHEELDIR := latest-wheel

build:
    @rm -fr $(WHEELDIR)
    @mkdir $(WHEELDIR)
    # output will be something like $(WHEELDIR)/foo-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
    # I don't know what "poetry build" does

upload: build
    aws s3 cp $(WHEELDIR)/* s3://some-bucket/
```

If you like, you can add a line or two to store a copy of the wheel in `dist/`, or some other archive.